# Comparing string variables in Athena

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

```
Table

   Animal   Animal_type   col3  col4
   rabbit   rabbit-me     abc.  def
   rabbit   norabit       xyz   def
   lion     lion-me       xyz   abc
   king     kong-me       abc   xyz
```

SELECT *  FROM table where animal like Animal_type + '-me'

I am trying to write a query which compares two variables in athena but unable to get it working.

I tried % but it doesn't work either

Expected output
row 1 and row 3 to be selected

Comment: Please add sample input and output data to your question.

Comment: I added sample table and expected output as requested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `CONCAT` function:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = CONCAT(name, '-me');
```

Or, use the ANSI `||` concatenation operator:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = name || '-me';
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try
SELECT * FROM table where animal like CONCAT(animal,'%-me') or
SELECT * FROM table where animal = CONCAT(TRIM(animal),'-me')